# How can we store Steps in constants of a Shepherd JS Tour?

Tags: javascript, java, html, module, element

Following problem:
I want to dynamically change the attachTo of the current Step in a Shepherd JS Tour. To do so, im going to use "tour.getCurrentStep().updateStepOptions()". If i changed the "attachTo" option, i want on some cases to jump back to the default "attachTo" option. For that, i need a instance that i definied before calling the updateStepOptions() from the current Step. I want something like this:

```
const attachToElement = tour.getCurrentStep().attachTo
if(...) {
   tour.getCurrentStep().updateStepOptions({attachTo: {attachToElement.element, on: "top"}});
} else {
   tour.getCurrentStep().updateStepOptions({attachTo: {attachToElement.element, attachToElement.on});
}
```

However this doesnt work, because the "attachToElement" is not defined. Does anybody know how to get over this?